# Getting data to refresh in a loop displayed on multiple pages

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an Angular application where I am trying to refresh data every 30 seconds to display a new page of data. After we have reached the end of the pages we go to the beginning. getData() is the source of my project data. Currently the project data displays all at once and I'd like to display by some limit on page and have the it refresh. kioskmode() method is executed in ngOnInit().

```
kioskmode()
{
    timer(10000, 30000).subscribe(timer=> { this.getData(); });
}
```

Comment: you're calling the same method again and again so you will get the same data, does your backend supports this?

Comment: you need make your api pagination capable. Then on frontend you can use setInterval() to call API every x seconds. when you reach on End of Records then call first page again.